# Kali for Raspberry Pi 3: exploitdb update hangs and does nothing

Tags: kali-linux, raspberry-pi

I have a serious problem in my Kali for Raspberry Pi 3: I've followed a video on YouTube to expand Kali and install a full version. I've started the process, and after about 4 hours, it has frozen and did nothing. So I cancelled the installation and did `dpkg --configure -a`. Then I've updated Kali and started upgrade. Now, the same problem.

It hangs on

> Unpacking exploitdb (20160808-0kali) over [same archive]

Can anyone please help?

Comment: This isn't a security problem, it is a configuration problem.  It should probably be on unix.SE.  You can flag your question and ask a moderator to move it.  But, at least provide a link to the video in question and explain what you did.

Answer (score 9):

I had this exact issue on NetHunter. But googling the problem wasn't useful and only resulted in a lot of unanswered threads. I'll list my solution here and hope it also works for non-NetHunter systems. It worked for me, it might not work for you.

I managed to solve the problem by first uninstalling man-db and exploitdb:

```
apt-get remove man-db
apt-get remove exploitdb
```

For the people reading this having this issue on NetHunter, this will also **automatically uninstall** `kali-linux-nethunter`. Don't worry about it, just reinstall it after fixing exploitdb.

At this point, dpkg gave me a message stating the following:

> dpkg: error processing package exploitdb (--remove): package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should reinstall it before attempting a removal

However, you can't reinstall it because it will get stuck at unpacking. To force the removal, use this command:

```
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq exploitdb
```

This command took 5 minutes on my OnePlus 3t NetHunter device. I imagine it taking forever on a RaspBerry Pi. Reinstalling exploitdb takes even longer.

After that you can reinstall the packages and it should work. Don't forget to reinstall `kali-linux-nethunter` if you're using NetHunter.

Answer (score 2):

Even i installed it today , it takes alot of time to process it as the pi is very slow compared to a pc took me roughly 4 hours just to extract the exploitdb package , the reason is that it had more than 37,000 files to process . The solution is just wait and not to panic